# How to get the machine type of the machine accessing an application on a server using .NET?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to do different things in my application based on whether the machine accessing the web based program is a mobile device such as an Iphone or droid or if it is a desktop or laptop.

Is there a way for me to know if the application is fired off by an iphone or some other mobile device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the browser capabilities object that comes with HttpRequest object.

Check this article in MSDN:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yekbd5b(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: unfortunately it seems as though it's getting the browser info from the server or something. I'm accessing the program via the web from an Iphone and browser.Mobile device is False and Browser.Type is showing as Desktop....

Comment: That's because maybe browser capabilities object is outdated and/or mobile browser is unsupported. BTW, you can check browser's name, version.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and it works. Only problem is that it names Chrome as MAc/Safari, but it will do. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, glad to know it was useful for you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the info you need from the Request.Browser object.

Good sample code can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yekbd5b.aspx